# Decoding bas64 string in asm (masm32 ) by crypt32

Tags: assembly, winapi, base64, masm, masm32

I have been recently occupied in learning assembly and i'm now playing with masm32 and crypto API, but i need a little help to start.
How can i decode an input string  base64 encoded using CryptBinaryToString? It seems I wrong something because I can't decode a simple message passed through a Text box.

I have tried to put encoded string into a buffer without success.

Comment: From the function name and docs, it looks like `CryptBinaryToStringA` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptbinarytostringa) can perform Base64 **en**coding.  For decoding, you'd want `CryptStringToBinaryA` - take a Base64 string as input, output to an array of binary bytes (which might happen to be plain ASCII, or might not.)

Comment: use asm exist sense only for very special code, which hard or impossible implement on more high level language, but not for such task. however code can look like https://pastebin.com/VqU4fGYf

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I finally managed to find the error. I first used CryptStringToBinaryA passing only the pointer to the text to be decoded and the address of the variable containing the length of the decoded string, then I allocated in memory the space necessary to contain the plaintext and I called again the function with all the parameters. I know that asm is not useful for this task but as I told It was just an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice, I finally managed to find the error. I first used CryptStringToBinaryA passing only the pointer to the text to be decoded and the address of the variable containing the length of the decoded string, then I allocated in memory the space necessary to contain the plaintext and I called again the function with all the parameters. I know that asm is not useful for this task but as I told It was just an exercise.

Comment: You don't need to call it twice, you can calculate the size of the output from the size of the input for plain Base64 with no headers.  (Every 8 bits of input become 6 bits of output, hence the name base64, so every 4 bytes of input becomes 3 bytes of output.  `outside = (inside << 2) / 3` calculated without overflow.)